# Why are some of the items in my JPanel not showing?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add several JTextFields, JButtons, and JLabels to a Panel, however only the buttons are showing. I have set the layout to be null for my JPanel and I have set locations/bounds for each item.

[image]

```
frame= new JFrame("Find and Replace");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
        JLabel findLabel = new JLabel("Find:");
        findLabel.setLocation(0, 20);
        JLabel replaceLabel = new JLabel("Replace with:");
        replaceLabel.setLocation(50, 60);
        findField = new JTextField(20);
        findField.setLocation(30, 100);
        replaceField = new JTextField(20);
        replaceField.setLocation(220, 140);
        replaceAllButton = new JButton("Find and Replace All");
        replaceAllButton.setBounds(20, 200, 100, 25);
        replaceButton = new JButton("Replace");
        replaceButton.setBounds(120, 200, 100, 25);

        panel.add(findLabel);
        panel.add(findField);
        panel.add(replaceLabel);
        panel.add(replaceField);
        panel.add(replaceButton);
        panel.add(replaceAllButton);
```

Comment: The sizes of the "missing" components are 0. However, the **real** problem is using `null` layout. Use layout managers, as swing was designed to be used, and the components' sizes would be automatically determined, the window would behave well when resized, and so on. `null` layouts may look easier at first glance, but will lead to no end of trouble.

Comment: Hmm, how could I use the GroupLayout for this? I saw some examples of different layouts here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html, and to me the GroupLayout looks very nice

Comment: `GroupLayout` likely works, but it is rather difficult to use manually. I prefer combining layouts, instead of trying to solve the entire layout problem at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GridBagLayout instead of using null layout here:

```
    GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    panel = new JPanel();
    findLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    findField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    replaceLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    replaceField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    replaceAllButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    replaceButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    findLabel.setText("Find :");
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 94;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 30;
    panel.add(findLabel, gridBagConstraints);
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 149;
    panel.add(findField, gridBagConstraints);

    replaceLabel.setText("Replace With :");
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 34;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 23;
    panel.add(replaceLabel, gridBagConstraints);
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 149;
    panel.add(replaceField, gridBagConstraints);

    replaceAllButton.setText("Find And Replace All");
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 9;
    panel.add(replaceAllButton, gridBagConstraints);

    replaceButton.setText("Replace");
    gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
    gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 99;
    gridBagConstraints.ipady = 8;
    panel.add(replaceButton, gridBagConstraints);
    //adding panel to the jframe
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
```

Comment: Actually, a `null` layout is less likely to cause the issue that the OP is describing, where as using a layout manager can, under certain circumstances. The point is (yes they should use a layout manager), but without a clear picture what the OP is doing, it's impossible to provide an answer as to why some of the components don't appear

Comment: @MadProgrammer without an Insets from the JPanel are added to the JFrame, and part are behind, covered by JPanel

Comment: @mKorbel It's possible to know. The `JPanel` is never added to the `JFrame` in the example code, is that the root cause of the problem or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

you added all objects to the        panel but forgot to add        panel to        frame (object of JFrame) 
add this line to your code

`frame.add(panel);`

Comment: He didn't show his whole code. Otherwise he also wouldn't have been able to show us a picture of the frame (containing the components). kiheru's comment already answers the question.